# Combine two strings for file path in SAS

Tags: variables, sas, filepath, sas-macro

I have two strings that I want to combine to get the file path to be used in a PROC IMPORT statement in SAS

```
%let TypeName = XYZ;
%let InputDirectory = \\Nam1\Nam2\Nam3\Dataset\;
%let FileType = Filing.csv;
%let Filename = &TypeName&FileType;
%put &Filename;
%let CompInputDirect = &InputDirectory&Filename;

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE= %sysfunc(&CompInputDirect)
OUT= outdata
DBMS=csv
REPLACE;
GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

I get an error message saying that

```
ERROR: Function name missing in %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function reference.
```

How do I put a macro variable containing the full file path in the Proc Import statement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you meant to use QUOTE function.

```
%sysfunc(quote(&CompInputDirect))
```

Or you can supply your own quotes.

```
"&CompInputDirect"
```

Comment: Hi @data_null Thank for that!

Answer (score 2):

Macro symbol resolution `&<name>` is more formally `&<name>.`  The `.` is often left off when the resolution occurs where other characters or tokens break up the submit stream.

You want to be careful if you have abstracted a dot (`.`) filename extension.  You will need double dots in order to resolve filename and dot separate the extension.  A good habit when dealing with filename parts is to use the formal resolution syntax.

Example:

```
%let folder = \\Nam1\Nam2\Nam3\Dataset\;
%let file = XYZ;
%let ext = csv;

proc import datafile = "&folder.&file..&ext." ...
                                     ^^
```